# How to remove get parameter value after form submission

Tags: php, session

I have a form and i can add datas to the table and store it in the session. what my problem is when ever i click remove button the id is in the url. so i cant add other datas.

I need to get rid of the get value after i click remove

its like this http://localhost:8085/examples/buyme.php?del=2
i need it to be like this
http://localhost:8085/examples/buyme.php

```
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
  
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                
                <th>Action</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    

<tbody>
            
                    <tr>
            
                    </tr>
                <?php
                if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"])){
                    $values;
                    $total=0;
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys=>$values){
                        $amount = $values["quantity"]*$values["price"];
                        $total=$total+$amount;
                ?>
                         <tr>
                             <td> <?php echo $values["id"] ?> </td>
                      <td> <?php echo $values["pname"] ?> </td>
                      <td> <?php echo $values["price"] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $values["quantity"] ?> </td>
                    
                    <td><a href="buyme.php?del=<?php echo $values["id"]  ?>"> Remove</a> 
                             <a href="#editProductModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            
                             
                             
                             </td>
                      <td> </td>
                      
                  </tr>
                 
                <?php   }?>
                <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                      <td>Total </td>
                     <td><?php echo $total ?> </td>
                    
                      <td> </td>
                    <?php } ?>  
                  </tr>
                    <!-- Removing from cart -->
            <?php   
                if(isset($_GET["del"])){
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys=>$values){
                    if($values["id"]==$_GET["del"])
                    {
                        unset($_SESSION["cart"][$keys]);
                       

                        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";//to refresh page after submit
                    }
                    }
                    
                }
                    
                
                ?>
                <br>
  <br>
 
                    
                 </tbody>
                  
</table>
```

Please help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to `redirect` page to `buyme.php` after deleting/unsetting `session` values, for that replace this line in your code:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";//to refresh page after submit
```

with this:

```
header('Location: http://localhost:8085/examples/buyme.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be more safe to send the `id` for deletion not by a `GET` request but by a `POST` request. To make this possible you have to insert a `<form>` with `method="POST"` and a hidden input field with name `del` and the `id` you want to delete for each item.
Then you have to handle the `POST` call in your script.

For example like this:

```php
if($_POST['del']) {
  # your delete action here
}
```

By using a `POST` request it is not possible to change the `id` via url.